# Unable to use Crate JDBC 2.6.0 in read only mode

Tags: java, jdbc, cratedb

I want to restrict delete/update statements

This is what I am trying

`ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("delete from test where id=243640033")`

Ideally `executeQuery` method of JDBC should not allow update, delete and etc. But Crate Database is simply executing delete queries. Then I tried `connection.setReadOnly(true)` and it did not work

Is there any way to restrict Crate JDBC doing update/delete/drop operations from `stmt.executeQuery(somequery)` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a CrateDB user with [Data Query Language (DQL) privileges](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/4.6/admin/privileges.html#dql) only and subsequently use this user to connect with JDBC. This will prevent all `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE` / `DROP` operations.

```
CREATE USER read_only WITH (password = '<secure-password>');
GRANT DQL TO read_only;
```

If required you can further restrict access only to specific schemas, tables or views. Compare the documentation on how to achieve this.

Comment: thanks, exactly what I am looking for